# Qtwebengine on Embedded linux, with qtwayland and OpenGL not working, black rectangles seen on browser

Tags: opengl-es, embedded-linux, qtwebengine, arm9, qtwayland

I'm trying to get web browsing working on my platform with Qt.

I'm using Qt 5.4.1, on ARM A9, running embedded linux, with qtwayland and OpenGL ES. I've successfully compiled (using yocto) QtWebEngine for the platform and I'm able to launch the example browser applications (quicknanobrowser, browser and fancybrowser) .

The issue is that the web contents are appearing as black rectangles. All other widgets/menu of the browser are working fine.

This issue has been reported and there is a fix for the EGLFS (https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/pull/4/files?diff=split ). Since my setup is based on the wayland EGL, I'm not sure if porting this fix to wayland EGL would help.

Could someone let me know what would be going wrong? Any ideas on where to start debugging?